# JPA Native Query delete in

Tags: jpa, native, delete-row

I try to delete a list of rows from a table using this Native Query:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="WebGroup.DeleteIn",
query="DELETE FROM WebGroup WHERE
WebGroup.GROUP_ID IN (:IDsList)"

getEm().createNamedQuery("WebGroup.DeleteIn")
              .setParameter("IDsList", groupToDeleteIDs)
              .executeUpdate();
```

and this is the SQL that MySQL executes:

```
DELETE FROM WebGroup WHERE WebGroup.GROUP_ID IN (:IDsList)
```

SO, JPA doesn't replace the variable IDsList...

Some one could help me please?

Comment: I am not sure if a Collection is supposed to be expanded in a **native** query.

Answer (score 4):

One way that works is if you not use the id value like you tried, but instead use the entity and let JPA handle the identification of it like this:

```
HashSet<Transaction> transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
... 
entityManager.createQuery(
  "DELETE FROM Transaction e WHERE e IN (:transactions)").
  setParameter("transactions", new ArrayList<Transaction>(
  transactions)).executeUpdate();
```

Hope it helps you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

native queries do not support collection expansion neither named parameters.

you should write:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="WebGroup.DeleteIn", query="DELETE FROM WebGroup WHERE WebGroup.GROUP_ID IN (?,?,?,?)"

Query query = getEm().createNamedQuery("WebGroup.DeleteIn");
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) query.setParameter(i + 1, groupToDeleteIDs.get(i));
query.executeUpdate();
```

but it is **horrible**

on eclipselink + mysql this one works:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="WebGroup.DeleteIn", query="DELETE FROM WebGroup WHERE WebGroup.GROUP_ID IN (?)"

Query query = getEm().createNamedQuery("WebGroup.DeleteIn");
query.setParameter(1, StringUtils.join(groupToDeleteIDs, ",");
query.executeUpdate();
```

however it is not very nice...
but there isn't any other solution using a named query.